# Javascript ajax if then else

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following javascript which is supposed to pop a notification to the user if the php script bellow returns a mysql select count result higher than 0:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            function update() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../ajax/alert/notification.php',
                    timeout: 1000,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#notification-alert-main").text(data);
                        $("#notification-alert-detailed").text(data);
                        if (data > 0) {
                            $("#notification-alert-message").innerHTML('<i class="fa fa-warning danger"></i> New alert has been detected');
                        }
                        window.setTimeout(update, 5000);
                    },
                });
            }
            update();
        });
    </script>
```

The php script:

```
<?php
  include('../../db.php');
  $queryCountUnreadAlerts = $bdd->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) Nb FROM exp_alert WHERE ale_read = 0;");
  $queryCountUnreadAlerts->execute();
  $dataCountUnreadAlerts = $queryCountUnreadAlerts->fetch();
  $queryCountUnreadAlerts->closeCursor();
  echo(intval($dataCountUnreadAlerts['Nb']));
?>
```

The web browser reports me an error:

`[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#notification-alert-message").innerHTML('<i class="fa fa-warning danger"></i> New alert has been detected')')
    success (index.php, line 230)
    l (jquery.min.js, line 4)
    fireWith (jquery.min.js, line 4)
    k (jquery.min.js, line 6)
    (anonymous function) (jquery.min.js, line 6)`

I suspect a wrong variable type, but still I am working with integers all the time.

Comment: `innerHTML` is a DOM node property, not a jQuery method, use `.html('...')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JQuery, you use `.html()`, not `.innerHTML`

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 3):

Use `.html()` instead of `innerHTML`

Or

change as follow

`$("#notification-alert-message").get(0).innerHTML="<i class='fa fa-warning danger'></i> New alert has been detected";`

Comment: Show the response you got from the post.. the value in `data`